# Is there a way to trigger xcode's run from bash?

Tags: xcode, command-line

I have found `xcodebuild` which can be used like so:

> $xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj

I was hoping `xcoderun` would be a command too, but it is not.  I checked `man xcodebuild` and couldn't find anything about running the project after build.  I've looked into the idea it might involve a flag related to "schemes" or "configuration", but adding `-configuration Debug` was of no help and it really seems like configuration and scheme are much larger than what I'm looking for.

**How can I build then run my xcode project from command line?**

Comment: What good would it do you to run a project from the command line? The purpose of automated running is to run a _test_ on your project, and that is something you can readily do.

Comment: I'm trying to add a "build_system" argument to my ".sublime-project" file to allow me to compile and run my project without leaving sublime.  One of the properties I need to do this is a bash command.  My xcode project has some details in it's scheme for run that I would like to keep in one place.